# Alert Message through email or phone(Message)

Tags: login, wp-login-form

Hi all I am newbie I need to know how to alert email or message while attempt login if success or if failure .That alert mail describe that login IP and date and time .

Is it possible to do this following in wordpress.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Successful log-ins trigger the action `wp_login`, failures `wp_login_failed`. Phone calls are not built-in, you need a separate plugin for that.

Example with email:

```
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'wpse_79917_login_failed' );
add_action( 'wp_login',        'wpse_79917_login_success', 10, 2 );

function wpse_79917_login_failed( $username )
{
    wp_mail( 
        get_option( 'admin_email'),
        'Login failed',
        'custom message'
    );
}
function wpse_79917_login_success( $user_login, $user )
{
    wp_mail( 
        get_option( 'admin_email'),
        'Login successful',
        'custom message'
    );
}
```

Comment: yeh This is the one ..what i was looking  for Many thanks ...